# permission for accessing files are denied and some sessions are killed

Tags: kerberos

I ssh to a Linux server which runs kerberos.
This is the first time I met Kerberos.

After some time of being idle or loging out and loging in,  I found some strange things, which I am not sure if are created by Kerberos:

1. I was denied to  access my files. When I list these files, I see:

   ```
   drwxrwxr-x.  2 tim reg 2048 Apr 10 15:43 doc
   drwxrwxr-x.  2 tim reg 2048 Apr  7 16:59 etc
   ???????????  ? ?    ?     ?            ? README.md
   ???????????  ? ?    ?     ?            ? setup.sh
   ```
2. My shell processes running in Screen or Tmux are gone (or killed)

What shall I do to solve the two issues? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Kerberos credentials expire after a set amount of time. This is set up by the site admins, typical is about 24hrs.

Your real problem is that your home directory is likely in AFS which is a distributed filesystem that uses kerberos for authentication.

What you need to do to regain file access is to aquire a new kerberos ticket and AFS token. ( tokens are special tickets that live in process space to allow the kernel to access AFS servers on your behalf. )

The exact commands will vary from site to site, but generally

```
kinit 
aklog
```

will restore your access to the filesystem. You can find out more about AFS 
at the OpenAFS website.

[OpenAFS Website](http://www.openafs.org)

Comment: Thanks. Can we write and run some command/script to  automatically renew and extend my credentials?

Comment: No, you need to type the password to renew credentials. If your site supports renewable tickets you should look for a program called krenew that can keep a ticket alive for up to a month depending on how the kerberos realm is configured. http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/kstart/krenew.html

Comment: (1) When shall I run the renew command? If the credential expires in 24 hrs, do I have to run the renew command  anytime before it expires? (2) Once I type it, will it expires in a month or just like logging in freshly and expires in another 24 hrs?